# Get 1 result in first column of the table and get all the results in the second column of the table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tables like these:

**users**

```
   id   |   firstname   |   lastname   |   date   
--------------------------------------------------
   1    |   paul        |   sy         |   date   

   2    |   james       |   curry      |   date   

   3    |   kevin       |   leonard    |   date
```

**docs_list**

```
   id   |   user_id   |   url   |   title   |   date   
-------------------------------------------------------
   1    |      1      |   url   |   title   |   date   
   2    |      2      |   url   |   title   |   date   
   3    |      1      |   url   |   title   |   date
```

I want to get 1 result of `firstname` and `lastname` and all of the results of  `url` and `title` **based on where** the `users.id` and `docs_list.user_id` is equal to the **id** given `ORDER BY docs_list.date DESC`.

So this is how I query it:

```
SELECT users.first, users.last, docs_list.urlcode, docs_list.title

FROM users

INNER JOIN docs_list

ON users.id = docs_list.user_id

WHERE docs_list.user_id = {$value}

ORDER BY docs_list.date DESC
```

Problem is that, I got so many `firstname` and `lastname` results (equal to how many rows I have in the `docs_list` result). I only need 1 `firstname` and `lastname`.

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, that i made based on your given table.

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname

FROM users u

JOIN docs_list dl

ON u.id = dl.user_id

WHERE dl.user_id = {$value}

GROUP BY 1
```

If you want to get one result one row for firstname and lastname you just can select firstname and lastname only. Because if there's url and title, they have different value for each row so if you group by them i would be error because url and title have different value.
*Correct me if i'm wrong :D

Comment: I tried to use `GROUP BY users.firstname, users.lastname` and `GROUP BY docs_list.url, docs_list.title` and both of them did not work.

Comment: try use my query that i've made from your given table sir.

Comment: same results as I have now. and thanks for the quick response much appreciated.

Comment: hmm, but i already try my query on my database that i made from your table it going okay, not return any duplicate row.

Comment: I don't know, but for me I have`firstname` and `lastname` duplicates on my result. Note: I just copy + paste your code and this is what I got.

Comment: hmmm, do you mind if let me try use your database? so i can debug easily with your database sir.

Comment: I'll think about it, can you give me a screen shot of your code and the result?

Comment: is that like what you want ?

Comment: we have the same result, you see, the last table have 2 `firstname` and `lastname` named `paul` and `sy`. So we have the same result. ` 
is that like what you want ?` unfortunately, no, what I want is a single result of `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: oh i see, that's happen because in docs_list table there are two user_id = 1 that makes it result two row right? and the value of url and title for each row must be different right?

Comment: try again to look my answer sir, already revised. Hope my answer will be usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to do a clean presentation on web page which is without duplicate first names and last names? If that is the case I think you need to separate presentation from data retrieve. (Or you can retrieve your data separately)
From my point of view, you cannot use "group by" because it will cause you to lose other data such as url and other non-duplicate fields.

Comment: `without duplicate first names and last names` yes, because I do not need it, I only need 1 pair of it. So what your trying to say is I need to do 2 queries? `you cannot use "group by"` yes I can't.